# API Routes: Multiple operations with path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to configure my API routes, and I can't seem to get around this error from Swagger:

> 500 : {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Not supported by Swagger 2.0: Multiple operations with path 'api/Doors/{OrganizationSys}' and method 'GET'.

I understand why I am getting the error, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here are the API end points:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int organizationSys)
{
    ....
}

public IHttpActionResult Get(int organizationSys, int id)
{
    ....
}


public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Doors door)
{
    ....
}

public IHttpActionResult Put([FromBody]Doors door)
{
    ....
}

public IHttpActionResult Delete(int organizationSys, int id)
{
    ....
}
```

And here are my routes, which are clearly not correct:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "route1",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{organizationSys}"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "route2",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{organizationSys}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
);
```

**UPDATE:**

I now have this, but get the same error:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "route1",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{organizationSys}/{id}"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "route2",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{organizationSys}"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
);
```

**UPDATE 2:**  This is what I have now....

Getting closer, I think.

```
[Route("api/Doors/{organizaitonSys}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int organizationSys)
{
    ....
}

[Route("api/Doors/{organizaitonSys}/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int organizationSys, int id)
{
    ....
}

[Route("api/Doors")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Doors door)
{
    ....
}

[Route("api/Doors")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Doors door)
{
    ....
}

[Route("api/Doors/{organizaitonSys}/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult Delete(int organizationSys, int id)
{
    ....
}
```

And then the routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "route1",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{organizationSys}/{id}"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "route2",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{organizationSys}"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
);
```

However, when I try to call

```
GET: http://localhost:26307/api/Doors/1012
```

or

```
GET: http://localhost:26307/api/Doors/1012/23
```

or

```
DELETE: http://localhost:26307/api/Doors/1012/23
```

I get 404 errors. And now in Swagger, the `organizationSys` parameter shows up twice in the Try It section:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`route1` and `route2` have the same mapping because of the optional `{id}`. remove the optional parameter and put `route2` before `route1` as `route1` is more general.

You can also provide constraints, which restrict how a URI segment can match a placeholder:

```
constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }   // Only matches if "id" is one or more digits.
```

Example

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "route2",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{organizationSys}/{id}",
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }   // Only matches if "id" is one or more 
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "route1",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{organizationSys}"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
);
```

There will also be an issue mapping to

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int OrganizationSys, int DoorID) {
    ....
}
```

because of the `DoorID` parameter, which does not match that of the route template. rename it to `id` or update the template to match.

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int organizationSys, int id) {
    ....
}
```

If using attribute routing then make sure it is enabled before convention-based routes

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.

       //...code removed for brevity
    }
}
```

Then apply the routes to the controller via attributes.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Doors")]
public class DoorsController : ApiController {

    //matches GET api/doors/5
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{organizationSys:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int organizationSys) {
        //....
    }

    //matches GET api/doors/5/1
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{organizationSys:int}/{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int organizationSys, int id) {
        ....
    }    

    //matches POST api/doors
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Doors door) {
        //....
    }

    //matches PUT api/doors
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("")]    
    public IHttpActionResult Put([FromBody]Doors door) {
        //....
    }

    //matches DELETE api/doors/5/1
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("{organizationSys:int}/{id:int}")]    
    public IHttpActionResult Delete(int organizationSys, int id) {
        //....
    }    
}
```

Note the use of `RoutePrefix` attribute to reduce repeated template parts and route constraints.

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: I really appreciate your help Nkosi. I've updated my OP again.  Fixed the parameter names and cases, and added the routes as you suggested.  I still get the same error.

Comment: did you remove the optional default

Comment: ah, no!  But.. it won't let me do a constraint w/o a default

Comment: Have you added a route to the top of one of the controller methods to differentiate them? such as attribute [Route("api/organization/organizationsys/id/{id}")]

Comment: @TaylorMaxwell -- ah ha!  Now we are getting somewhere!!

Comment: @CaseyCrookston so you have attribute routing enabled?

Comment: I was wrong.  Not working yet.  I deleted my answer and added a new update to the OP

Comment: Just saw your edits, Nkosi.  I'll try them and report back