# Not supported by Swagger 2.0: Multiple operations with path 'api/Client' and method 'GET'

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

In my web api, I have 2 Get Methods, One to get all clients and one to get client by ID

```
  [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetClients()
    {
        var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
        try
        {
            var roles = await CosmosStoreHolder.Instance.CosmosStoreClient.Query().ToListAsync();
            return Ok(roles);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var dt = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Error Lulo: ", guid }
            };

            telemetry.TrackException(ex, dt);
            return BadRequest("Error Lulo: " + guid);
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetClient(string clientId)
    {     
        var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
        try
        {
            var clientStore = CosmosStoreHolder.Instance.CosmosStoreClient;
            var client = await clientStore.Query().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == clientId);
            if (client == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(client);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            telemetry.TrackException(ex);
            return BadRequest("Unknown error");
        }
    }
```

I just installed swashbucckle and configured according to this:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implementing-swagger-in-web-api/

However I get the error below

> `500 : {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Not
>   supported by Swagger 2.0: Multiple operations with path 'api/Client'
>   and method 'GET'. See the config setting -
>   \"ResolveConflictingActions\" for a potential
>   workaround","ExceptionType":"System.NotSupportedException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGeneratorOptions.DefaultConflictingActionsResolver(IEnumerable`1
>   apiDescriptions)\r\n at
>   Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.CreatePathItem(IEnumerable`1
>   apiDescriptions, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry)\r\n at
>   Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetSwagger>b__4(IGrouping`2
>   group)\r\n at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector,
>   IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)\r\n at
>   Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String rootUrl, String
>   apiVersion)\r\n at
>   Swashbuckle.Application.SwaggerDocsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at
>   System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.HttpServer.d__0.MoveNext()"}
>   https://webapi-app.azurewebsites.net/swagger/do`cs/v1

Comment: I don't think you have identified the correct problem.  You have 2 different functions with /similar/ names (GetClients vs GetClient).  Swagger should have no problems with this.

Comment: Do you have a second function called `GetClient` that has a different set of parameters?

Comment: See if this helps: [Not supported by Swagger 2.0: Multiple operations with path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39601890/113116), [Web API: Same Method with different HTTP Verbs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35000024/113116), [API Routes: Multiple operations with path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49056556/113116)

Comment: Thanks @Neil I checked and I dont have duplicated endpoints, this is indeed rare

Comment: Test changing `clientId` to int `GetClient(int clientId)` just a test see if the path is different...

Comment: set the attribute on top of both methods [Route(api/GetClients] and [Route(api/GetClient)]

Comment: check this, is the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39412998/swashbuckle-set-manualy-operationid the fix was to specify manual one by one the name for swagger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the string parameter, strings are nullable by default.
The routes of your actions:

- `GetClients()`
- `GetClient(string clientId)`

will be the same.

If it was an integer the route will look like:
`/api/Controller/{clientId}`
and will not conflict with the GetClients.

Changing data type might not be an option, you might be forced into using routes:

---

Looking at some of my examples I found this controller using routes and multiple Gets:

http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Location#/

[image]

You can see I have multiple gets under the same controller, but they do have slightly different actions:

```
[RoutePrefix("Location")]
public class LocationController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Get1")]
    public GeolocateResponse Get1([FromUri] GeolocateResponse x)
    {
        return x;
    }

    [Route("Get2")]
    public Location Get2([FromUri] Location x)
    {
        return x;
    }
```